# ios - storyboards custom segue if/else?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

.

Hello,

I am trying to make a Custom Segue for my storyboard. Now I notice that it seems that a segue can only go one way.

Is that true? Or can I set an if/else statement in there?

I have tried this, but after the initial tab/click the button becomes useless.

Have  I missed something?

I kinda have this in mind. In the commented areas I have code, but I am after the principle of the idea.

```
- (void) perform{
CGFloat ledge = 25;
CGSize screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size;
BOOL left = TRUE;



MainViewController *src = (MainViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
SideMenuVC *dst = (SideMenuVC *) self.destinationViewController;

// [src presentViewController:dst animated:YES completion:nil];
[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:YES];    

if(left){

   //Do the first thing, but the view is still partly in the screen

}else {    


    //Return to original place

}
  }
```

Comment: I dont quite get it, you are trying to do something AFTER pushing a new ViewController to your navController's stack?

Comment: Yup I want to pop up part of a view and then dismiss it. I am just trying to understand the concept:-)

Comment: Ah I see, so you want to stop up the animation to check for something, and then move back if _something_?

Comment: Yup kinda, I am wanting to see if the facebook app slide menu can be done via Storyboard. I have found repositories on Github to it, but that is all in code. Now that is not bad, but it is not going to help me with my Storyboards:0)

Comment: Now I get it, I misunderstood. You could always send a boolean to your next ViewController, telling it "how much" to load, and handle it in viewWill/viewDidAppear. :)

Comment: Yeah, but the FB App brings the button with it and stays on the same View and then brings it back. I tried the Boolean but the button becomes numb after it is pressed once.

Comment: Yea, you can't go back with the same button I assume?

Comment: No it does not seem to be. I guess frameworks are packed with a lot of complicated code for a reason:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately UISegues are only one way. You have to dismiss modal UIViewControllers manually or use popViewControllerAnimated: for UINavigationController.

Comment: So it seems, ok back to the drawing board:-)